# Retrieving objects from memory or Mongo DB query in Go

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a Mongo collection with around 5000 entries with an average size of `3.98KB`. The data is updated periodically. Sometimes in every minute, sometimes twice a day.
While running my GO program, I have to be able to retrieve single and multiple entries based on the current function. The task is to retrieve the data fast as possible. My question is that storing objects in a slice and query it with for loops, will outperform a properly indexed Mongo query?

Comment: You have to measure and see. However, scanning an array of 5K entries almost always outperforms the fastest database lookups. DB lookups usually will be in the millisecond range, and scanning a 5K array will likely be in the microsecond range.

Comment: I agree with "measure and see". But if you have to query anyway, it's almost always better to let the database index and fetch the data -- otherwise you'd have to return about 20MB of data over the network, only to throw most of it away! However, if you have the data in an in-process cache anyway, it might well be faster to use that (especially if you have it indexed by a map of ID (or whatever you're filtering on).

Comment: @BenHoyt is correct. MongoDB manages the data set quite meticulously, trying to keep the most used data in RAM. Reinventing the wheel and trying to implement a distributed sync here does not make much sense, imho. Of course a slice from memory will always outperform a query (by SEVERAL orders of magnitude), but that does not take into account the overhead required for syncing and the potential lack of consistency. What I would do is to use an aggregation to query the data as needed, skipping any processing on the clientside.